# Vue-Cli3 and the recent Node-Sass DoS advisory: How to replace node-sass with dart-sass?

Tags: npm, vue-cli-3, node-sass

I have an app created with Vue-Cli and it uses node-sass. Recently, I ran npm audit and is informing me there is a [new advisory](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/961) for `node-sass` with the following info:

> All versions of node-sass are vulnerable to Denial of Service (DoS).
>   No fix is currently available. Consider using an alternative package
>   until a fix is made available.

Thus, I can't deploy my app to the company's enterprise cloud (DevOps pipeline).

Does anyone know how I can fix or replace `node-sass` with `dart-sass` and whether there are any specific updates or changes I need to do with my app?

Kinda shooting in the dark here...not much out there at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: same here, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, follow the link below

https://www.priestch.com/replace-node-sass-with-dart-sass-in-vue-cli3-based-project/

Thanks

Comment: Yes I did that too. Thanks.